# Web API authentication via Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How does one go about tying in AD authentication to an existing Web API? I've attempted to do this with Azure but Azure doesn't play nice with Web APIs. The constant redirects are a nightmare. Is there some way I can set it up to just hit a local AD sever, authenticate the user, and get back a token? It seems like it should be fairly simple but I'm finding no information on this.

Comment: There seems to be plenty of articles out there: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+api+azure+active+directory+authentication. What **specifically** is not working or have you tried.

Comment: @Igor I'm trying to get it to work with Azure but Azure is forcing me to do a redirect to a Microsoft website to login. This redirect looks completely unprofessional for one and for two it stops the Visual Studio debugger which means that after the login is complete and the user is redirected back to the website I can't test anything else because the debugger has stopped. Reattaching the debugger to the window doesn't work either because it doesn't hit any breakpoints.

Comment: @Igor that's for _Azure_ AD, which is different than a local AD instance, which Microsoft no longer supports out of the box as they did prior to the Identity system for authentication.  Unfortunately from my experience, the answer seem that you need to roll your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always be redirected if you're using Azure AD. You shouldn't be able to do this locally to my knowledge.